# Microsoft Access 2013 date issue

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I made access application some of my query depend on date and here it is

```
Set sales = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select *  From sales where action_date = #" & date_actions & "#")
```

When I change the date format to "dd/mm/yyyy" in my windows, this query don't work.  When I retrive it to the default which is "mm/dd/yyy" it work. I try to change region to United Kingdom because it use the "dd/mm/yyyy" format but it also don't work. Is there any setting or something to add to my query to make it work with any format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid locale issues by using the unambiguous ISO date format when you build your `SELECT` statement:

```vb
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "Select * From sales where action_date = #" & _
    Format(date_actions, "yyyy-m-d") & "#"
Set sales = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSelect)
```

Another approach, which entirely avoids format issues, is to use a parameter query:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim sales As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSelect As String
strSelect = "Select * From sales where action_date = [which_date]"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strSelect)
qdf.Parameters("which_date") = date_actions
Set sales = qdf.OpenRecordset(strSelect)
```